# Eclipse crashes elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Oxygen from snapcraft (also attempted with the download from the official site). Eclipse launches, gets to about 25% complete on the load, and then elementary OS crashes, I lose all control over the system and I have to power-cycle my computer to restart. Is there any way to fix this?

- elementary OS version: 0.4.1 Loki
- Eclipse version: Oxygen 4.7.3a

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem.
I solved it with editing eclipse.ini file:

Go to ~/eclipse/java-/eclipse/eclipse.ini

Open eclipse.ini with your favourite text editor.

Add

`--launcher.GTK_version`

`2`

Before "--launcher.appendVmargs”

Save and try starting eclipse. : - )

Comment: Thank you this really worked I have been trying to get this to work for over 2 weeks.

Comment: Great to hear that! :)

Comment: Unbelievable this issue still exists more than 5 years later! JS version 6.6.0 I had to adjust /opt/tibco/TIB_js-studiocomm_6.6.0/Jaspersoft Studio.ini and add the fix on the 3rd line.  I was'nt running into fatal issues, but all window decorations where double causing the main dialog buttons to be unusable